# ¿Diferencia en beforeUnload si se origino por el usuario refrescar la pagina o cerrar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, web, aplicación-web

Hay alguna manera de distinguir en el beforeUnload cuando se activa por un F5-boton de refrescar o por cerrar la pestaña de la pagina, ya que el este activa con ambas operaciones, no se si el event contiene pistas sobre su causa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías diferenciar el evento del botón F5 añadiendo un listener al window así

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  // Evento del boton F5
  if (event.keyCode === 116) {
    // Haz algo
  }
})
```

Probé añadiendo el listener a un div en especial, en tu caso a una referencia pero al parecer el listener solo funciona cuando lo añades a window, si deseas evitar que el botón F5 recargue la página podrías añadir `event.preventDefault();`